# Chrome Extension - Display Popup on Mouse Over

Tags: popup, google-chrome-extension, mouseover

Both `browserActions` and `pageActions` let you display a popup when certain events happen (e.g button click). How can I display a popup when I mouse over some content on the page (e.g. a hyperlink)?

Cheers,

{ete

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't, but you can try to load your popup *(chrome.extension.getURL("popup.html"))* in an iframe on page

Comment: Tweetbeat manages to do it (or, at least, manages to do something equivalent): https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/jgepnjcnamgjgmmlonednfonidanijpo

Comment: @Peter Tweetbeat displays a regular div on top of a page, it has nothing to do with browserActions and pageActions chrome popups. Just a plain javascript solution.